# Why the copy constructor didn't work when the function returned?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm new to C++, I'm confused of the copy constructor.

When I run my code below, it only shows me `constructor` and `destructor` without `copy-constructor`.

But when the function `foo_bar()` returns a object `point`, shouldn't a copy of `point` be created and returned?

I don't understand, or maybe there are some misunderstandings.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point {
  public:
    Point() { cout << "constructor Point()" << endl; }
    Point(const Point &point) {
        cout << "copy constructor Point(const Point&)" << endl;
    }
    ~Point() { cout << "destructor ~Point()" << endl; }
};

Point foo_bar() {
    Point point;
    return point; // copy constructor???
}

int main() {
    Point A;
    foo_bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result of my code.

```
constructor Point()
constructor Point()
destructor ~Point()
destructor ~Point()
```

I think there should be a `copy-constructor`.

Comment: Compiler is allowed to optimise away any copy or move operations without keeping to as-if rule.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen or, post C++17, *required* to omit copying in these cases

Comment: See [class.temporary](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#2)

Comment: @Caleth That's NRVO, it doesn't fall into mandatory copy elision. It would still fail if copy constructor was deleted: https://godbolt.org/z/vf8K597E1. But it's allowed to be omitted (and always was afaik)

Comment: C++ constructors have some additional requirements that they are obligated to fulfill (and the compiler expects them to fulfill).  One being that they cannot have necessary side-effects, *because* the compiler is allowed (or in some situations, required) to elide the constructor if it can be elided.  The code presented is such a situation (where the "necessary side-effect" is `cout` character output).